# appear on scroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have written the css js and html for this simple appear on scroll and it still wont run in html? maybe its the way im connecting it in my html but that seems fine i have searhed many sites to confirm its right... i dont know where im going wrong.

```
.aboutfilmandcrew {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
}




#filminfo{

    padding:1em;
    border:.1em solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
    margin: 2em;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;    
}

#crew{


    padding:1em;
    border:.1em solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
    margin: 2em;
    width: 40%;
    float: right;

}

        <div class="aboutfilmandcrew">

      <div id="filminfo"> 
        Neuromancer, a novel written by William Gibson in 1984, takes place in the near future in a cyberpunk setting. Cyberpunk is a genre that focuses on future societies where technology has advanced, but crime and corruption have as well. Common features include globe-spanning mega-corporations, cybernetically enhanced mercenaries, and the importance of technology as a tool for crime.
        The story follows the experiences of Case, an out-of-work hacker who is contacted by a mysterious new employer called Armitage. Along with Molly, a mercenary cyborg, and a thief/illusionist named Peter Riviera, Case participates in a series of data thefts for their employer.  Based on the novel, and helmed by master director Ridley Scott, NEUROMANCER features a star studded cast that includes Ryan Gosling, Lucy Liu, Hayden Christensen and Benedict Cumberbatch.

            <br/>
            <h4> GENRES </h4>
            Sci fi/Adventure
          </p>

        </div><!---aboutfilm-->

      <div id="crew">
        <p>Director Ridley Scott </p>
        <p> Screenplay by Drew Goddard </p>
        <p> Based on the Novel By William Gibson </p>
        <p> Producers Simon Kinberg, Ridley Scott, Michael Schaefer, Aditya Sood, Mark Huffam </p>
        <p> Actors Ryan Gosling, Lucy Liu, Hayden Christensen and Benedict Cumberbatch </p>



        </div><!---crew-->
    </div><!---aboutfilmandcrew-->



$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (y > 200) {
    $('.aboutfilmandcrew').fadeIn();
  } else {
  console.log("<");
    $('.aboutfilmandcrew').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/cafuwujoyi/edit?html,js,output does this work ?

Comment: hi, yes it works but it just dissapears after it appears ? in my norepadd ++ file it doesnt do anything on scroll

Comment: that is whats confusing me... it works when i put it on a web based service like js bin or js fiddle but when i run it in notepad++ nothing happens

Comment: I'm not sure how are you executing code in Notepad++ ? Do you getting any exception in browser, what version of jQuery you are using ?

Comment: i can send the file onto you if you like? its just basic and i know it should work but its not. its very fustrating.

Comment: If you mention a "Launch in <anybrowser>" from notepad++, then your code won't work in the browser, because you didn't format the file by HTML standarts. At least It should have some obligatory tags at beginning

Comment: would it be possible to send it onto you ? im just a beginner and i am not sure of the html standards. all i know is that you have to link your js file to your html file and ive done that. and it still isint working.

Comment: is it different of that you uploaded in your question?

Comment: no its the same. but i feel the notepad ++ might be affecting it

Answer (score -1):

Change `$(document)` to `$(window)` and it should start working.

Comment: You sure your content is tall enough for scroll to happen? If you can't scroll the page yourself, the code will not trigger

Comment: yes i even added more height to the page for it to more scrollable and still nothing is happening